# bad alignment when using xparse, tabularx and enumerate

Tags: environments, tabularx, enumitem, alignment, xparse

I want to extract this piece of code into an environment

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{a} & a \\ \midrule
    \textbf{b} & b \\ \midrule
    \textbf{c} & c \\ \midrule
    \textbf{d} & d \\ \midrule
    \textbf{e} &
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*),nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}]
      \item x
      \item y
    \end{enumerate} \\ \midrule
    \textbf{f} & e \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
```

Wanted usage:

```
\begin{ucbx}{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}
  \item x
  \item y
\end{ucbx}
```

I am currently using the `xparse`, `tabularx`, `float`, `booktabs` and `enumitem` packages:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ucbx}{+m+m+m+m+m}{%
\table[H]
\tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\textbf{a} & #1 \\ \midrule
\textbf{b} & #2 \\ \midrule
\textbf{c} & #3 \\ \midrule
\textbf{d} & #4 \\ \midrule
\textbf{e} &
\enumerate[leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*),nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}]
}{%
\endenumerate \\ \midrule
\textbf{f} & #5 \\ \bottomrule
\endtabularx
\endtable
}
```

This code does not produce the wanted output and also throws `You can't use \relax' after \the.`, `Misplaced \noalign.`, `Undefined control sequence.`, `misplaced alignment tab character &.` and `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to  end.` errors.

I am using `XeLaTeX` for compilation.

Current output:
[image: current output]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `\enumerate` and `\endenumerate`, but the proper `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`, but this would conflict with `tabularx`.

Solution: if you don't plan to have `\verb` material in the items, you can use the `b` argument specifier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,enumitem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ucbx}{+m+m+m+m+m +b}{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \toprule
  \textbf{a} & #1 \\ \midrule
  \textbf{b} & #2 \\ \midrule
  \textbf{c} & #3 \\ \midrule
  \textbf{d} & #4 \\ \midrule
  \textbf{e} &
  \begin{enumerate}[
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\arabic*),
    nosep,
    after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
    before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}
  ] #6
  \end{enumerate} \\ \midrule
  \textbf{f} & #5 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{ucbx}{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}
  \item x
  \item y
\end{ucbx}

\end{document}
```

No need to call `table` if you don't have a caption.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! May i ask what the `center` environment is for? Isn't the table already 'centered' because of the `X` and `\textwidth` in the `tabularx` definition?

Comment: @Jordie It provides some space before and after and nullifies the paragraph indentation. You can as well use `flushleft`